# Django rest framework and react Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '')

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching some data with react from django rest framework and put them into state. And then pass them into another component with props. When I print them I get the object and it works perfectly. For example `console.log(props.user1)` gets me this:

```js
Array(1)
0:
   {
     date_joined: 2023-09-06T16:07:37.214335Z"
     email: ""
     username: "t"
   }
...
```

But when I print `props.user1.username` I get

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Comment: you're sending it as an array, not an object

Comment: Yeah but even when I write ``props.user1[0]`` I get `` Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`` Also when I write with ``typeof`` I get object

Comment: Check if `props.user1` exists and if it does then `props.user1[0]`, as it can be the case due to async nature

Answer (score 0):

it is look like:

`0: { date_joined: date, email: String username: String }`

if you want to get username, you have to use
`props.user1.0.username`
you can't use
`props.user1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was way more simple.

I had defined state like this:

`const [user,setUser] = useState()`

instead of this

`const [user,setUser] = useState([])`

And I should print it like this `console.log(user[0]?.username)`